# Алгоритм метод простых итераций

Tags: алгоритм, функции

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать приведение к виду x = f(x) в методе простых итераций, если функция имеет вид x^3 - 2*x^2 - 15*x  + 36 ?

Comment: А вспомните-ка условие сходимости метода простых итераций?

Comment: |1-k * f `(x)|<1 - условие сходимости. И как из него получить x = f(x)?

Answer (score 1):

Ладно, хотел вас самого навести на размышления и понимание, но увы - нет времени.

Для таких функций строить новую функцию можно как

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну, а самый простой выбор подходящей функции [image: введите сюда описание изображения] так, чтоб выполнялось условие сходимости -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, убедитесь сами:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double it(double x)
{
    return ((2*x-2)*x*x-36)/((3*x-4)*x-15);
}

double f(double x)
{
    return ((x-2)*x-15)*x+36;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    double x = 10, y = 0;
    while(abs(x-y) > 1e-7)
    {
        y = x;
        x = it(x);
    }
    cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    cout << "f(x) = " << f(x) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за помощь :)

Comment: Если устраивает - не оставляйте подвисший вопрос, принимайте ответ...